# Rails 6 - "where" sql queries without question marks (?)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-6

Why `where` sql queries without question marks `(?)`?

When I try:

```rb
User.find_by_last_name("a")
```

it generate:

```sql
User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."last_name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["last_name", "a"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

When:

```rb
User.where("last_name = ?", "a")
```

then:

```sql
User Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (last_name = 'a') LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

It also fails to make secure queries with LIKE:

```rb
User.where("last_name LIKE ?", "%a%")
```

it generate:

```sql
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (last_name LIKE '%a%') LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @benjessop my question: why `User.where("last_name LIKE ?", "%a%")` not generate something like this `User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."last_name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["last_name", "%a%"], ["LIMIT", 11]]`